# British colony in Berlin

Tags: british-empire, imperial-germany

Yesterday's [23rd May 2013's] IHT had [this](http://www.nytimes.com/2013/05/24/opinion/global/100-75-50-years-ago.html) interesting historical news clip in its 100, 75, 50 years ago section. It refers to a British colony in Berlin in 1913 of which Mr. J. W. Louth was apparently the dean.

> Before breakfast their Majesties received a deputation from the
>   British colony in Berlin, which presented a loyal address.

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=j%20w%20louth&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Territorial_evolution_of_the_British_Empire#Europe) aren't much help here.

What British colony are they referring to?

Comment: Probably just the expat community.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Quite likely (give the title dean). But always best to confirm.

Comment: As @FelixGoldberg notes, the word colony there most probably means the British expat community. However, I couldn't find a dictionary that would suggest such a definition for colony and I went ahead and [asked about it](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6757/what-does-the-word-colony-means-in-the-context-of-a-british-colony-in-berlin) on our sister site, English Language Learners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colony is being used here more in the ["biological" sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colony_%28biology%29). Strictly this means a group of individuals of the same **species** living closely together, but here it's being co-opted to mean a group of individuals of the same **nationality** living outside their own country but retaining their own culture and society to keep themselves distinct from the native population.

Comment: Makes sense, always thought the British were a different species ;)